# Publishing to /move_base_simple/goal

Tags: navigation, move-base, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,
This is a fairly straightforward question, however I have not been able to find it so far. Could someone please tell me the terminal command to publish move_base_simple/goal.
I know it is something like:
rostopic pub /move_base_simple/goal geometry_msgs/PoseStamped ..........

Really appreciate it. Thank you
Ammar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47973/publishing-to-/move_base_simple/goal/) by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2012-11-11

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
rostopic pub /move_base_simple/goal geometry_msgs/PoseStamped '{header: {stamp: now, frame_id: "map"}, pose: {position: {x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, orientation: {w: 1.0}}}'
```

See [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/YAMLCommandLine) for an overview of the command line yaml syntax.

But if you want to send goals programmatically, consider using actionlib. It allows you to preempt goals, i.e. stop the robot, while it is moving. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 24

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never mind! Found the answer. It is simply:

rostopic pub /robot_0/move_base_simple/goal geometry_msgs/PoseStamped '{ header: { frame_id: "/map" }, pose: { position: { x: 0.25, y: 0 }, orientation: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1 } } }'

Thanks

---

Originally posted by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) with karma: 289 on 2012-11-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gagan](https://answers.ros.org/users/94017/gagan/) on 2022-01-18**:
Hi Ammr,

If possible can you explain how did you manage to fix this by adding robot_0 in your command?
Why did you choose to do that?

**Comment by [faisalam1n](https://answers.ros.org/users/117922/faisalam1n/) on 2022-09-20**:
Hi @Gagan, I don't know why Ammar did /robot_0/ but I'm also doing it because I'm launching multiple turtlebots that's why I have to specify which robot I'm giving the goal pos to.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the sake of completeness and given that this is something rather useful to do especially for debugging reasons, here's the same command in ROS 2:

```
ros2 topic pub /move_base_simple/goal geometry_msgs/PoseStamped '{header: {stamp: {sec: 0, nanosec: 0}, frame_id: "map"}, pose: {position: {x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, orientation: {w: 1.0}}}'
```

---

Originally posted by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) with karma: 257 on 2019-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5